# Help with iphone button pressed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to see which button was clicked on so I can preform the correct logic.

This is the code for the buttons:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 423, 60, 60)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"refreshicon.png"] 
    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tag = 1;

UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 423, 60, 60)];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button2 setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"] 
    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.tag = 2;

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:button];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:button2];
```

And this is how I call the `buttonPressedAction`:

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
 UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;

if(button.tag == 1)
{
     NSLog(@"1");
}else 
{
     NSLog(@"2");
}
}
```

But when I use `NSLog` to see what the sender value is, it crashes.

Any advice for what's happening and how to correct it?

**Now corrected :o) THANKS!**

Comment: What's the crash? Unrecognized selector, or something else?

Comment: Since when does UIButton have a `value` method?

Comment: I am also suspecting an unrecognized selector. What are you expecting the [sender value] to return? To my knowledge, UIButton has no property named like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have pointed out, UIButton does not have a value property. I guess you are trying to detect which button was clicked. Here are two ways to do this:

1. Use the `tag` property one each button. I.e. button1.tag = 1, button2.tag = 2. You can then test which button was clicked with `if(sender.tag == 1)` etc. You could introduce constants for the numbers to make the code more readable.
2. If you keep a reference to the button, you can check if the reference is equal. Example: `if(sender == self.button1)`

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: Guess we wrote it at the same time, happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be to give buttons that do different things different actions, but failing that, you could distinguish them by tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    // do something
}
```

If you were saving the pointers to the button objects you are creating, you could compare the pointers. Or you can just set the `tag` property for the button, and use that to switch behaviour.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I added the code from Mads Mobaek to this as well and it works just fine :o)